# Reorder Array Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it possible to add a button to the HTML that would push one of the list items to the end of the list?

So like reorder the list, but not drag and drop; but when the button is pushed the first one i.e gets pushed to the end of the list.

I would really ppreciate the help.
This is the part of the typescipt:

```
cardz: Array< {}>; 
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public alerCtrl: AlertController, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

this.cardz = [

  {id: '2', name: 'Trainer A', code: 1, isrc: "assets/img/t2.jpg", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/a.jpeg"},

  {id: '1',name: 'Trainer B', code: 2, isrc: "https://i.imgur.com/bbtiwSH.gif", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/b.jpeg"},

  {id: '3',name: 'Luan B.', code: 3, isrc: "https://i.imgur.com/S9pDBNv.gif", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/pp.jpg"},

  {id: '4',name: 'Trainer D', code: 4, isrc: "https://i.imgur.com/1v9LkYa.gif", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/pp1.jpg"},

  {id: '5',name: 'Trainer E', code: 5, isrc: "https://i.imgur.com/Xkvlm4B.gif", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/one.jpeg"}
```

And here is the html:

```
<ion-list no-lines>
<ion-card *ngFor="let thing of cardz; let i = index;">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="{{thing.ppsrc}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2 (click)="openHome()">{{thing.name}}</h2>
        <p>23 Jan 2019</p>
    </ion-item>
    <img class="big" src={{thing.isrc}}>
  <ion-card-content>
    <h1>{{thing.title}}</h1>  
    <p>{{thing.content}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: I don't want to write the code out for you but you might want to look into the array.splice() then array.push() methods. Oh what the hell here's the idea: `items = Object.assign({}, array); array.splice(0, 1); array.push(items[0]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with those lines:

```
later (no){
 var item = this.cardz[no];
this.cardz.splice(no,1);
this.cardz.push(item);
}
```

And in the HTML I just had to add the i

```
<button ion-button icon-start clear small (click)="later(i)">
<ion-icon name="alarm"></ion-icon>
<div>Do later...</div>
</button>
```

Hopes this helps anyone who has the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about pushing the first item to the end of the list, it can be done like this:

```
const reorderedCardz =
  cardz
    .slice(1) 
    .concat(head(cardz));
```

To make it type-safe, we need to make sure the collection has at least one element. Let's create a type to support our design.

```
interface NonEmptyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
  0: T;
}

function head<T>(collection: NonEmptyArray<T>): T {
  return collection[0];
}
```

Our model now looks like this:

```
interface Card {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    code: number;
    isrc: string;
    ppsrc: string;
}

const cardz: NonEmptyArray<Card> = [
  {id: '2', name: 'Trainer A', code: 1, isrc: "assets/img/t2.jpg", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/a.jpeg"},
  {id: '1',name: 'Trainer B', code: 2, isrc: "https://i.imgur.com/bbtiwSH.gif", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/b.jpeg"},
  {id: '3',name: 'Luan B.', code: 3, isrc: "https://i.imgur.com/S9pDBNv.gif", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/pp.jpg"},
  {id: '4',name: 'Trainer D', code: 4, isrc: "https://i.imgur.com/1v9LkYa.gif", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/pp1.jpg"},
  {id: '5',name: 'Trainer E', code: 5, isrc: "https://i.imgur.com/Xkvlm4B.gif", ppsrc: "assets/imgs/one.jpeg"}
];
```

And our reordering function:

```
function reorder<T>(collection: NonEmptyArray<T>) {
    return (
        collection
          .slice(1)
          .concat(head(collection)) as NonEmptyArray<T>
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
const reorderedCardz = reorder(cardz);
```

See [TypeScript playground](https://links.wtf/PNqF).

Comment: Thank you for your time, but unfortunately it didn't work.
I get the error that 'interface' is an unexpected token.
Plus when I add the lines to the click event, it doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: If `interface` is an unexpected token, it means you are not using TypeScript. I added a link to TypeScript Playground. You can see the generated JavaScript there.